# Plesk backend with Letsencrypt

Tags: debian, ssl, plesk, letsencrypt

I have a debian server with plesk and letsencrypt (via plesk) installed. Is it possible to use these plesk-generated certificates which are normally only for the subscriptions/domains **to secure the plesk backend** on port 8443 ?

It would be nice, bacause plesk automatically renews these.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/plesk/letsencrypt-plesk/issues/11#issuecomment-166916633). If you access plesk via the domain you want to secure, you are able to tick a corresponding checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done... Just create a domain for your server itself... In my case I had a domain with vs-xxxxx.au.syrahost.com:8443... By creating this domain within plesk, I was able to use LetsEncrypt to secure my plesk control panel.

Set up a basic hosting profile for the primary server domain, then run the Letsencrypt app from the admin login.

Just remember to tick the box to "secure" plesk with this cert.

Note, I should point out, that as I have a vps, there is an A record pointing to my Plesk IP which is required for the ssl cert.